# combine two option groups in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a subform and several option groups.

It works fine to select records on the subform with 1 single option group, 
but I'm trying to combine two or more option groups.

I'm using this code for 1 option group:

```
Dim strFilter As String

Select Case [Frame26]
Case 1
     'Forms!YourFormName.Form.FilterOn = False
Case 2
     'strFilter = "[YourFieldName] = 'Open - Normal' Or [YourFieldName] = 'Open - Urgent'"
     'Forms!YourFormName.Form.Filter = strFilter
     'Forms!YourFormName.Form.FilterOn = True
case3
```

enz.....

Comment: Do the same thing with the second frame - just get the results from a second filter (strFilter2) and concatenate them to the first strFilter before you apply it. `strFilter = strFilter & strFilter2`

Answer (score 0):

**Here's example of implementing your second option frame:**

```
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strFilter2 As String

Select Case [Frame26]
Case 2
     strFilter = "[YourFieldName] = 'Open - Normal' Or [YourFieldName] = 'Open - Urgent'"
case3
'............

End Select

' Add second filter - replace all your logic and fields to fit second options
Select Case [Frame<##>]
Case 2
     strFilter2 = "[YourFieldName] = 'Open - Normal' Or [YourFieldName] = 'Open - Urgent'"
case3

if strFilter = "" AND strFilter2 = "" Then
     Forms!YourFormName.Form.FilterOn = False
     Exit Sub
End If

If strFilter <> "" AND strFilter2 <> "" then
    ' Join both filters
     strFilter = "(" & strFilter & ") AND (" & strFilter2 &  ")" 
Else If strFilter2 <> "" then
     ' Just Using second filter
     strFilter = strFilter2
End if

Forms!YourFormName.Form.Filter = strFilter
Forms!YourFormName.Form.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: it seems to work fine. where should i put it for the best; on click or after update.

Comment: I'd use a button 'Update Filter' and add to click event instead of AfterUpdate   just so you won't be updating the filters before each option group has been selected and changed